# C++ Operator overloading errors

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to write a basic piece of operator overloading code. However, I am getting a few errors which I cannot explain. 

Header file:

```
class Overloading
{
public:
    int number;
    Overloading();
    Overloading(int);
    Overloading operator+(Overloading);
    void vUselessoverloadFunction();
};
```

C++ code:

```
Overloading::Overloading()
{}

Overloading::Overloading(int i)
{
    number = i;
}

Overloading Overloading::operator+(Overloading Object2)
{
    Overloading NewObject;
    NewObject.number = number + Object2.number;
    return (NewObject);
}
void Overloading::vUselessoverloadFunction() {

Overloading ObjectOne(15);
Overloading ObjectTwo(24);
Overloading ObjectThree();

ObjectThree = ObjectOne+ObjectTwo;
cout << ObjectOne.number << endl;
cout << ObjectTwo.number << endl;
cout << "Overloaded object value: " << ObjectThree.number << endl;

}
```

I am getting the following errors:

On line `ObjectThree = ObjectOne+ObjectTwo;`:
-Assignment of function 'Overloading ObjectThree()'

 -Cannot convert 'Overloading' to 'Overloading()' in assignment

 and on line `cout << "Overloaded object value: " << ObjectThree.number << endl;`
 -Request for member 'number' in 'ObjectThree', which is of non-class type 'Overloading()'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A most vexing parse

Answer (score 3):

`Overloading ObjectThree();` is a *function prototype*.

It does *not* declare a variable `ObjectThree`. So your compiler outputs an error, albeit a rather confusing one.

This is quite a common error: Google for "most vexing parse".